# Is there a way I can make a checkbox input in AngularJS return false if it's not selected?

Tags: angularjs

My code is like this:

```
<input data-ng-model="status.correct" type="checkbox" /></div>
```

The field appears on the page but if it's not clicked then when the data goes to my database it shows a value of `null` whereas I would like it to show as `false`.

Comment: You can initialize your model to false using `ng-init`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ng-init for initializing the value

`<input ng-init="status.correct=false" data-ng-model="status.correct" type="checkbox" /></div>`

Comment: is it more 'correct' to ng-init vs $scope.status.correct = false in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize "$scope.status.correct=false" in the controller of your angular js.
And while passing value to database from your submit function in angular js pass "status=$scope.status.correct"